# iPhone application login encryption

Tags: iphone, encryption, authentication

I need make iPhone aplication to send username and password and then get token. I was looking for simply to use iPhone AES library, but I haven't found anything usable. Or should I use SSL (HTTPS) ? Can you recommend me best way how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any internet traffic that requires security should use SSL. Just set up a web server with an SSL certificate, then pass the `https` URL to a `NSURLRequest` and it'll take care of the rest.